# Trouble using an equal sign in SQL trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblVisitors] (
    [Id]        BIGINT         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [IP]        NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [ProfileId] INT            NULL,
    [DateVisit] DATE           NOT NULL,
    [TimeVisit] TIME (0)       NOT NULL,
    [Browser]   NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [UserOS]    NVARCHAR (500) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_tblVisitors] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_tblVisitors_tblProfile] FOREIGN KEY ([ProfileId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[tblProfile] ([Id]) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

I wrote a trigger to avoid redundancy:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_tblVisitors_OnInsert]
ON [dbo].[tblVisitors]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NoCount ON;
    DECLARE @C INT;

    SELECT * 
    INTO #TEMP 
    FROM inserted A 
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                    FROM tblVisitors B 
                    WHERE (A.IP = B.IP) 
                      AND (A.DateVisit = B.DateVisit) 
                      AND (A.ProfileId = B.ProfileId));

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TEMP) = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'DUPLICATE RECORD DETECTED';
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        RETURN;
    END

    INSERT INTO tblVisitors (IP, ProfileId, DateVisit, TimeVisit, Browser, UserOS)
           SELECT IP, ProfileId, DateVisit, TimeVisit, Browser, UserOS 
           FROM #TEMP;
END
```

But as this part of the code does not work, redundancy occurs:

```
(A.ProfileId = B.ProfileId)
```

Because after deleting this section, the operation is performed correctly. But this condition must be checked.

Comment: Why not just create a `unique` constraint?

Comment: The design of the table and foreign key makes it impossible for us to use the 3 primary keys. And because of the use of this table, I should not use the uniqu key.

Comment: What possible reason could there be to implement a unique constraint in a trigger instead of an actual unique constraint? Do you know what a unique constraint is? It's not a primary key.

Comment: Stop blindly applying patterns to every coding assignment you have. There is no reason to "load" rows into a temp table. Just use the inserted table directly. And before you go further, consider that you are intentionally "dropping" the duplicate rows without informing the inserting process. Generally, this is not desirable since the inserting process will assume all rows inserted successfully if no error occurs. You should think  **very** carefully before you continue.

Comment: And to answer your question, we need to know the actual primary key of the table involved and what tuple (combination of columns) must be unique. Is it the three columns mentioned? I ask because your current logic should be sufficient (excluding the possibility of null values in any of the columns).

Comment: Another reason to consider using a genuine unique constraint rather than trying to roll your own is that your current attempt ignores duplicates if they're *both* inserted at the same time, be a single `insert` .

Comment: `create unique index on tblVisitors (ProfileId, DateVisit)`

Comment: Thanks @SMor `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;` added.

Comment: I suspect you want OR not AND. And just do `IF EXISTS ()` you don't need a temp table. And take care of NULL explicitly probably using `ISNULL`

Comment: Your updates indicate that you're moving in *exactly the wrong direction*. You've still not explained why you're not just using a unique constraint. In the meantime, you're effectively acting as if inserts only act on single rows (within the trigger) whilst using an `INSERT` style that explicitly recognizes the existence of multi-row inserts.

Comment: I would *strongly* suggest that you add a number of tables to your question - demonstrating both data that should be allowed and data that should be prevented (with explanations). Because clearly your current explanations are failing and we know, *by definition* that any code you're showing is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using my psychic skills, I suspect that you have `ProfileId` values that are `null`, and in SQL the expression `null = null` is not `true`, but your logic requires it to be `true`.

Try this:

```
AND (A.ProfileId = B.ProfileId OR (A.ProfileId IS NULL AND B.ProfileId IS NULL))
```

Comment: But since SQL Server unique constraints prohibit duplicate `NULL`s, it's still unclear why this trigger exists at all. Plus the "insert duplicates in a single insert" would still be allowed...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever but the def is: `[ProfileId] INT NULL` - ie nulls are allowed

Comment: A SQL Server unique constraint only allows a single `NULL`. As such, it's still unclear *why this trigger would be better than a unique constraint*, which is what many of the comments are trying to solicit from the OP. I.e. unique constraints in SQL Server are closer to `GROUP BY` than other constructs and, *in such circumstances*, `NULL`s are actually treated as not unequal.